# Query Help Needed with Kysely: Type Mismatch in whereRef Method

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma, kysely

I'm trying to grab 2 articles from my database and for each article, I want to get all its tags. I'm using jsonArrayFrom to bundle up the tags for each article. The weird thing is that I get the exact result that I was expecting, but Typescript keeps telling me that something is wrong.

Here is the full code of my kysely query

```
const data = await db
  .selectFrom("blog_articles as a")
  .orderBy("a.published_at", "desc")
  .limit(2)
  .select([
    "a.slug",
    jsonArrayFrom(
      db
        .selectFrom("blog_article_tags as bat")
        .innerJoin("blog_tags as t", "t.slug", "bat.tag_slug")
        .select(["t.slug", "t.name", "t.stage"])
        .whereRef("bat.article_slug", '=', 'a.slug'),
    ).as("tags"),
  ])
  .execute();
```

But, here's where I'm stuck.

```
.whereRef("bat.article_slug", "=", "a.slug")
```

While hovering over `a.slug`  typescript throws me this error

`Argument of type "a.slug" is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReferenceExpression<DB & { bat: BlogArticleTags; } & { t: BlogTags; }, "bat" | "t">'.`

What is funny to me, is that I get the exact result I was expecting to get, the only problem is that Typescript seems to not like it at all.